# Calling a method as the main activity

Tags: java, android, methods

I have a method, that for some reason only works well when it is called from the main activity. The problem is that I am trying to call it from another class.
Is there a way to call a method appearing as the main activity?

Comment: It sure would help to see your code.

Comment: Posting your logcat output would be helpful too.  You need to be more specific about exactly what is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always run your code in main thread by creating Handler on main looper:

```
Handler handler= new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

Then just call

```
handler.post(new Runnable(
  @Override
  public void run () {
    //  code that should be running from UI Thread
  }
));
```

Comment: That is just what I wanted.

Comment: Definitely I can read your minds =). "main activity" and Main Thread (UI thread) - it's quite different things

Comment: Well, I was talking about the main activity in android

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static method, call it like: MyActivityClass.myMethod(myArg1, myArg2).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your method is static and also public instead of private. Also, don't forget to include class as well. After that, you should be able to use any methods of an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a method from a different class, you need to make an instance of the class where the method is defined. Consider the two classes below:

```
public class Test{ 

 public void showMesage(){ 
 System.out.println("I am method showMessage from class Test!"); 
 } 
 } 

 public class TestCall{ 

 public void run(){ 
 Test.showMesage(); 
 } 
 } 


 Class Test has a method named "showMessage". The method "run" in TestCall class is trying to use the showMessage method. This will generate similar error that you are having. To resolve that, you need to make an instance of the class Test inside the run method like this: 

 public void run(){ 
 Test t = new Test(); // create an instance 
 t.showMesage(); // use t to refer any method of class Test 
 } 

 Or, you can make the method showMessage static like this: 

 public static void showMesage(){ 
 System.out.println("I am method showMessage from class Test!"); 
 } 

 Now, you don't need to change the run method anymore. If you have any questions, post 'em. 

 Additional Suggestion: 

 You can always write a method which will extract the array list for you like this: 

 import java.util.ArrayList; 

 public class Test{ 

 ArrayList al = null; 

 public void populateList(){ 
 al = new ArrayList(); 
 al.add("Apple"); 
 al.add("Mango"); 
 } 

 public ArrayList getList(){ 
 return this.al; 
 } 
 } 

 import java.util.ArrayList; 

 public class TestCall{ 

 public void run(){ 
 Test t = new Test(); 
 t.populateList(); 
 ArrayList aList = t.getList(); 
 System.out.println(aList.get(0)); 
 System.out.println(aList.get(1)); 
 } 

 public static void main(String[] strARgs){ 

 new TestCall().run(); 
 } 

 } 

 Further response: 

 In that case, you can declare the ArrayList as static so that you can access that arraylist from other class directly. For example, class Mango as a arraylist named aList like: 

 class Mango { 

 public static ArrayList aList = null; //this is a global variable 

 //some methods and stuff 
 ....... 
 ..... 
 } 

 This aList now can be accessed easily from other classes like: 

 import Mango; 
 class Apple { 
 ArrayList aList = Mango.AList; // direct call 
 ... 
 .... 
 } 
 Another thing, before you access the arraylist, you need to make sure that the event that populates the arraylist(dynamically) has been called already from the same class where you are trying to access the arraylist.
```

Comment: Please format code and answer when providing one.